# OpenWebKitSharp and WebKit.NET: Accessing inner iframes HTML content

Tags: c#, webkit.net

I've been using both **WebKit.NET** and **OpenWebKitSharp** libraries for a while with decent results. However, it seems that there's a task I can't overcome: I need to access the HTML contents / DocumentText of the main HTML document's internal iframes.

I can correctly get to the

```
frameLoadDelegate_DidFinishLoadForFrame
```

event for each specific IFrame, but the *IWebFrame* interface received by that delegate doesn't seem to contain anything useful in order to retrieve the frame HTML contents.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?